# How to select last three non-NULL columns across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, if my dataset looks like this:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6
---+------+------+------+------+------+-----
 A | a1   | a2   | a3   | a4   | a5   | a6
 B | b1   | b2   | b3   | b4   | NULL | NULL
 C | c1   | c2   | c3   | NULL | NULL | NULL
```

The desired output would be:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6
---+------+------+------+------+------+-----
 A | a4   | a5   | a6   |
 B | b2   | b3   | b4   |
 C | c1   | c2   | c3   |
```

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

I just found this thread: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210431/select-first-and-last-non-empty-blank-column-of-a-record-mysql

This allow me to pick the last non-null column, but I have no idea to to get the second and third last column in the same time as well.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I can only come up with COALESCE to select the first non-null column, but have no idea how to reverse that and expand to 3 columns.

Comment: In the first record, `col1` is replaced `col4` value but in 2nd row `col1` is replaced by `col2` ? 

You want to shift values to left based on `NULL` values in last 3 field ?

Comment: No it's not about shifting columns, it's about to pick the last 3 non-null columns and remove the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you request ([db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=88c77b9c3c4f0e78ae311da3ed9ca32f))

**Edit:** The initial version probably didn't do what you want if there were less than three `NOT NULL` values in a row. This version will shift them left.

```
SELECT Id,
       CA.Col1,
       CA.Col2,
       CA.Col3,
       NULL AS Col4,
       NULL AS Col5,
       NULL AS Col6
FROM   YourTable
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN val END) AS Col1,
                           MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN val END) AS Col2,
                           MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN val END) AS Col3
                    FROM   (SELECT val,
                                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ord) AS RN
                            FROM                    
                               (SELECT TOP 3 *
                                FROM   (VALUES(1, col1),
                                              (2, col2),
                                              (3, col3),
                                              (4, col4),
                                              (5, col5),
                                              (6, col6) ) v(ord, val)
                                WHERE  val IS NOT NULL
                                ORDER BY ord DESC
                                ) d1                            
                            ) d2                            
                    ) CA
```

Comment: Rly thank you for this. However, the last Non-Null column in my original dataset are all the same words, ideally for all the Col3 I should have the same word, but it returns different words after applying your code.

Comment: You must have implemented it wrong. Check the "ord" values are all correct order

Comment: You are right, I didn't implement it correctly, now it works fine. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pivot` and `unpivot` to achieve the desired result.

try the following:

```
;with cte as 
(
    select id, cols, col as val, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by cols desc) rn
    from @t
    unpivot
    (
        col for cols in ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6])
    )upvt
)
select id, ISNULL([3], '') as col1, ISNULL([2], '') as col2, ISNULL([1], '') as col3, '' col4, '' col5, '' col6
from 
(
    select id, val, rn from cte
)t
pivot
(
    max(val) for rn in ([1], [2], [3])
)pvt
order by 1
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63c0e844b23b64fb1b5033773019f9b9)**.

Comment: This does have the same issue as my initial attempt that it probably won't do what they want if there are `<3` eligible columns. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dfce4cb03ea47eb97937ab1e9274e0ba - it also will disassemble the unpivoted result into one massive resultset that needs a final aggregation step to re-unite elements from the same row together. The `CROSS APPLY` approach avoids that as it just calculates the values for each row as it goes

Comment: @MartinSmith you are right, Thanks for the insight. There must be 3 or more columns if they want to pick the last 3 non-NULL columns though and we can also make unpivot dynamic (it will be messier though) like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a344372371a0d6b5b75f118f1720bc7).